# how to parse invalid json while appending data from loop

Tags: python, json

I am appending json objects from loop but the problem is that the data goes into invalid json format. I am I have 1 million json objects in file and each time while I iterate I am appending more records into it.

this is my code

```
       for p_no in range(1,3):
            print(''.join([x,'?per_page=100&page={0}'.format(p_no)]))
            url = ''.join([x,'?per_page=100&page={0}'.format(p_no)])
            headers = {'Authorization': f'token {token}'}
            repo=requests.get(url,headers=headers,params=params).json()
            if repo:
                with open('data.json', 'a',encoding='utf-8') as f:
                    json.dump(repo, f, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
                continue
            else:
                break
```

When I am reading the json file I am getting JSONDecode Error

this is my json format

```
[
    {
        "login": "asu",
        "login_name": "heylo"
    },
    {
        "login": "sr9",
        "login_name": "heylo"
    }
],
[
    {
        "login": "tokuda109",
        "login_name": "mojombo"
    },
    {
        "login": "svallory",
        "login_name": "mojombo"
    }
]
```

Is there a efficient solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is it's appending as lists. You need them to be in 1 set of `[` `]`.

I would do that by combining them, and then write to file at the very end. See if this works:

```
jsonData = []
for p_no in range(1,3):
            print(''.join([x,'?per_page=100&page={0}'.format(p_no)]))
            url = ''.join([x,'?per_page=100&page={0}'.format(p_no)])
            headers = {'Authorization': f'token {token}'}
            repo=requests.get(url,headers=headers,params=params).json()
            if repo:
                jsonData += repo
                continue
            else:
                break


with open('data.json', 'w',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(jsonData, f, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

The other option is to do a string replace on the file. Replace `'],['` with just `','`

With `.replace()`:

```
import json

with open('C:/test/sample.json') as f:
    json_file = f.read()
    json_file = ''.join(json_file.split()).replace('],[', ',')
    data = json.loads(json_file)
```

Comment: can you provide with replace

Comment: edited it above to include replace option

Answer (score 0):

You are dumping several **valid** JSON objects into a file, but you are appending them one after another. This makes the whole file **invalid** json.

If your `repo` is like this:

```
[
    {
        "login": "asu",
        "login_name": "heylo"
    },
    {
        "login": "sr9",
        "login_name": "heylo"
    }
],
[
    {
        "login": "tokuda109",
        "login_name": "mojombo"
    },
    {
        "login": "svallory",
        "login_name": "mojombo"
    }
]
```

and you append it to the file several times, directly one after another, then you end up with something like this:

```
[
    {
        "login": "asu",
        "login_name": "heylo"
    },
    {
        "login": "sr9",
        "login_name": "heylo"
    }
],
[
    {
        "login": "tokuda109",
        "login_name": "mojombo"
    },
    {
        "login": "svallory",
        "login_name": "mojombo"
    }
][
    {
        "login": "asu",
        "login_name": "heylo"
    },
    {
        "login": "sr9",
        "login_name": "heylo"
    }
],
[
    {
        "login": "tokuda109",
        "login_name": "mojombo"
    },
    {
        "login": "svallory",
        "login_name": "mojombo"
    }
]
```

As you can see, this **is not a valid JSON**. Look at line 20. There is `][` sequence which is bad. Apart from that, your lists should be in some kind of "container" - in a list or in an object.

The solution would be to append `repo` objects to a list and keep them in memory. After your loop is done and you have several `repo` in that list, then you can dump the whole list into a file at once. This will generate the correct JSON file.